# Javascript button sound effect

Tags: javascript

I ran into a problem in a project I had done. I used the function I threw below to have a sound effect when we press the button. It works fine, but when I give direction to the button, there is no sound. Where could I be doing the mistake? Thank you.

```js
function playMyAudio() {
  document.getElementById("myAudio").play();
}
```

```html
<audio src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/audio/beep.mp3" preload="auto" id="myAudio"></audio>

<a href="index.html">

  <button onClick="playMyAudio()">Play Audio</button>
</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by direction? Please show HTML code

Comment: I added the HTML codes. thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by giving "direction"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what's happening is when the when you click on the button wrapped in a tag the link is making the browser load the link instead of calling the function ! ... Check this code snippet it will help you make link in a better way

Solution =>

```
<audio src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/audio/beep.mp3" preload="auto" id="myAudio"></audio>


<button href="index.html" onClick="playMyAudio()">Play Audio</button>

<script>

  const audioEl = document.getElementById("myAudio");
  function playMyAudio() {
    audioEl.play();
  }

  const buttonLinks = document.querySelectorAll("button[href]");
  const delay = 100;//milliseconds

  audioEl.addEventListener("canplaythrough", ()=> {
    buttonLinks.forEach(btn => {
      btn.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
        setTimeout(()=> {
          window.location = btn.getAttribute("href")
        }, audioEl.duration + delay);
      })
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `a` tag and redirect to `index.html` after a short delay using JS :

```
function playMyAudio(){
   document.getElementById("myAudio").play();
   setTimeout(() => window.location.href = "index.html", 200);
}
```

Comment: The solution you wrote worked. Another problem arose here. I want to apply this function to about 8 buttons.

Comment: @GÖKTUĞKARABULUT Then you should describe this new problem in another question.